# Find element in matrix according to column

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, search

I'm now "playing" with image processing. 
I'm uploading an .jpg image(RGB) to a matlab.  After that im getting info of height, width and dimension. Next step is dividing it into 3 matrixes(RGB) and making it gray.  Last step is binarizing it. I've got binarized image with data matrix which has size of ~900x1800.

I want to extract data from matrix

For each column I want to find all rows that hold the value equals `1`. For example: For column `1` I want to find all rows equal to `1` and for column `2` also `1`(beacuse it's binary matrix.

```
img = imread(jpeg);
inf2=imfinfo(jpeg); 
[height, width,  dim] = size(img); 
if dim == 3 
    R=img(:, :, 1);
    G=img(:, :, 2);
    B=img(:, :, 3); 
    gray_img=rgb2gray(img); 
    level=graythresh(gray_img); 
    img_bin2 = im2bw(gray_img,level); 
    img_bin2= ~img_bin2;
%     imshow(img_bin2)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me, what you want to extract from the columns. You got a binary image with 1800 columns and for each column you want to extract something. But what is that something, can you please try to explain again?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now: For the first column you want to find all row indexes where the value is equal to `1`. For the 2nd column you want to find all rows that are equal to `2` and so on. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes(like you said in second comment), and i want to save it to another matrix.

Comment: Or just find only the first position in row(for each column) which value is equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
data=randi(100,[10000 100]); % generate test data
compared=bsxfun(@eq,data,1:size(data,2)); % compare each value to their respective row index
result=cell(1,100); % create a cell array to store the result in. It needs to be a cell array instead of a matrix because each column can have a different amount of matches.
for ii=1:size(data,2)
    result{ii}=find(compared(:,ii)); % loop over the columns and find the row indexes for each column
end
```

You can do the same thing also without using bsxfun (maybe this is easier to understand):

```
data=randi(100,[10000 100]);
result=cell(1,100);
for ii=1:size(data,2)
    temp=data(:,ii)==ii;
    result{ii}=find(temp);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `arrayfun()` over your matrix `M` as below

```
arrayfun(@(k) find(M(:,k)==k),1:size(M,2),"UniformOutput",false)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it by myself, but guys thanks!

```
max_val_of_1 = find(num_of_1, 1, 'last'); 
for k = 1:width
  y_max_val = find(img_bin2(:,k),1,'first');
  y_val = max_val_of_1 - y_max_val;
  y(k) = y_val;
end
```